# Finding eigenfunctions using ladder operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, eigenvalue

Using $L_1\pm iL_2$ as raising and lowering operators I need to obtain an expression for $Y_{l,l}(\theta,\phi)$ and after this I need to find $Y_{l,m}(\theta,\phi)$ for $(l,m)=(1,1),(1,0),(1,-1),(2,2),(2,1)$ and $(2,0)$ The hint says that $Y_{l,l}(\theta,\phi)$, $Y_{1,1}(\theta,\phi)$, $Y_{2,2}(\theta,\phi)$ should be easy to find as they are in the kernel of $L_+$ and are eigenfunctions of $L_3$. I think I know how to 'lower' these to find the rest but I am struggling to find these. I got the stage where I have $Y_{l,m}(\theta,\phi) = P_{l,m}(\theta)e^{im\phi}$ and I'm not sure where to go from here, or if this is even correct! Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\langle \theta ,\varphi \vert  lm\rangle =Y_{l}^{m}(\theta ,\varphi )$, and consider
\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{L}_{-} &=&\hat{L}_{x}-i\hat{L}_{y} \\
&=&i\hbar \left( \sin \varphi \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }+\cos
\varphi \cos \theta \frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }\right) +\hbar \left(
\cos \varphi \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }-\sin \varphi \cos \theta
\frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }\right)  \\
&=&\hbar \left( e^{-i\varphi }\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }+\cos \theta
(i^{2}\sin \varphi -i\cos \theta )\frac{d}{d\varphi }\right)  \\
&=&\hbar \left( -e^{-i\varphi }\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }+i\cos
\theta e^{-i\varphi }\frac{d}{d\varphi }\right) =\hbar e^{-i\varphi }\left( -
\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }+i\cos \theta \frac{\partial }{\partial
\varphi }\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
L_{-}Y_{l}^{-l}(\theta ,\varphi ) &=&0 \\
L_{z}Y_{l}^{-l} &=&l\hbar Y_{l}^{-l}(\theta ,\varphi )\Longrightarrow -i\hbar%
\frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }Y_{l}^{m}(\theta ,\varphi
)=m^{2}Y_{l}^{m}(\theta ,\varphi ) \\
&=&Y_{l}^{m}(\theta ,\varphi )=g(\theta )e^{im\varphi }
\end{eqnarray}

The equation  $L_{-}Y_{l}^{-l}(\theta ,\varphi )=0$ translates into the differential equation
\begin{equation}
\left( -\frac{d}{d\theta }+i(-il)\cos \theta \right) g(\theta )=0
\end{equation}
with solution $g(\theta )=C_{l}(\sin\theta )^{l}$ so that
\begin{equation}
Y_{l}^{-l}(\theta ,\varphi )=C_{l}(\sin \theta )^{l}e^{-il\varphi }
\end{equation}

The integration constant $C_{l}$ is determined from the normalization condition
\begin{eqnarray}
\int d\Omega |Y_{l}^{-l}(\theta ,\varphi )|^{2}
&=&1=\vert C_{l}\vert ^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi }d\varphi \int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta \sin \theta (\sin \theta )^{2l} \\
&=&2\pi \vert C_{l}\vert ^{2}\int_{0}^{\pi }d\theta \sin \theta (\sin\theta )^{2l}
\end{eqnarray}

With this
\begin{equation}
Y_{l}^{-l}(\theta ,\varphi )=\sqrt{\frac{(2l+1)!}{4\pi }}\frac{1}{l^{l}2^{l}}%
(\sin\theta )^{l}e^{-il\varphi }
\end{equation}

To obtain the remaining spherical harmonics, consider  $\langle \theta
,\varphi |(L_{+})^{l+m}|l-l\rangle $ \ and recall that
\begin{equation}
\hat{L}_{+}|lm\rangle =\sqrt{(l-m)(l+m+1)}|l,m+1\rangle
\end{equation}

Then:
\begin{eqnarray}
(\theta ,\varphi |(L_{+})^{l+m}|l,-l\rangle &=&\langle \theta ,\varphi
|(L_{+})^{l+m-1}|l,-l+1\rangle \sqrt{2l\cdot 1}\hbar \\
&=&\langle \theta ,\varphi |(L_{+})^{l+m-z}|l,-l+2\rangle \sqrt{(2l)\cdot 1}%
\cdot \sqrt{(2l-1)\cdot 2}\hbar^{2} \\
&=&\langle \theta ,\varphi |(L_{+})^{l+m-3}|l,-l+3)\sqrt{(2l)(2l-1)(2l-2)%
\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3}\hbar
\end{eqnarray}
and generally:
\begin{equation}
\langle \theta ,\varphi |(L_{+})^{l+m}|l,-l\rangle =\sqrt{\frac{(2l)!(l+m)!}{%
(l-m)!}}\langle \theta ,\varphi |lm\rangle (\hbar)^{l+m}
\end{equation}

Hence,
\begin{equation}
Y_{l}^{m}(\theta ,\varphi |lm\rangle =\langle \theta ,\varphi |lm\rangle
\sqrt{\frac{(l-m)!}{(2l)!(l+m)!}}\langle \theta ,\varphi
|(L_{+})^{l+m}|l,-l\rangle \frac{1}{(\hbar)^{l+m}}
\end{equation}

Using
\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{L}_{+} &=&-i\hbar e^{i\varphi }\left[ i\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta
}-\cos \theta \frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }\right]  \\
&=&\hbar e^{i\varphi }\left[ \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }+i\cos \theta
\frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }\right]  \\
Y_{l}^{-l}(\theta ,\varphi ) &=&\sqrt{\frac{(2l+1)!}{4\pi }}\frac{1}{l!}%
2^{l}(\sin \theta )^{l}e^{-il\varphi }
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{equation}
\langle \theta ,\varphi |\hat{L}_{+}^{l+m}|l,-l\rangle =\hbar
^{l+m}e^{i(l+m)\varphi }\left[ \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }+i\cos
\frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }\right] ^{l+m}Y_{l}^{-l}(\theta ,\varphi )
\end{equation}
We finally arrive at
\begin{equation}
Y_{l}^{m}(\theta ,\varphi )=\sqrt{\frac{(l-m)!}{(2l)!(l+m)!}}\sqrt{\frac{%
(2l+1)!}{4\pi }}\frac{1}{l!2^{l}}\left[ e^{i\varphi }\left( \frac{\partial }{%
\partial \theta }+i\cos \theta \frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }\right) %
\right] ^{l+m}(\sin \theta )^{l}e^{-il}
\end{equation}

For example, consider the case where  $l=1$ .  Then,
\begin{eqnarray}
Y_{1}^{-1}(\theta ,\varphi ) &=&\sqrt{\frac{(2\cdot 1+1)!}{4\pi }}\frac{1}{1!}\frac{1}{2!}\sin \theta e^{-i\varphi }=\sqrt{\frac{6}{16\pi }}\sin \theta
e^{-i\varphi }=\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi }}\sin \theta e^{-i\varphi } \\
Y_{1}^{0}(\theta ,\varphi ) &=&\sqrt{\frac{(1-0)!3}{(1+0!4\pi }}\frac{1}{1!}
\frac{1}{2^{1}}e^{i(1+0)\varphi }\left( \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }
-i\cos \theta \frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }\right) ^{1}\sin \theta
e^{-i\varphi } \\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi }}\frac{1}{2}e^{i\varphi }\left[ \left( \cos \theta +i
\frac{\cos \theta }{\sin \theta }(-i)\sin \theta \right) e^{-i\varphi }
\right] =\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi }}\cdot \frac{1}{2}(2\cos \theta )=\sqrt{\frac{3
}{4\pi }}\cos \theta
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
Y_{1}^{+1} &=&\sqrt{\frac{(1-1)!}{(1+1)!}\cdot \frac{3}{4\pi }}\frac{1}{1!}
\frac{1}{2!}\left[ e^{i\varphi }\left( \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }%
+i\cos \theta \frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }\right) \right] ^{2}\sin
\theta e^{-i\varphi } \\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\cdot 4\pi }}\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\varphi }\left( \frac{
\partial }{\partial \theta }+i\cos \theta \frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }
\right) e^{i\varphi }\left( \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }+i\cos \theta
\frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }\right) \sin \theta e^{-i\varphi } \\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi }}\frac{1}{2}e^{i\varphi }\left( \frac{\partial }{
\partial \theta }+i\cos \theta \frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }\right)
2\cos \theta  \\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi }}e^{i\varphi }(-\sin \theta )=-\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi }}
e^{i\varphi }\sin \theta
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I'm a bit confused how you got the part: $L_{-}Y_{l}^{-l}(\theta ,\varphi ) =0$ and the following lines

Comment: @Deke The state with $m=-l$ is killed by $L_-$ so $\langle \theta\varphi\vert L_-\vert l,-l\rangle = L_-Y_l^{-l}(\theta,\varphi)=0$.  I didn't want to solve the problem for you so I started at the bottom of the ladder rather than at the top.